# Use the limit definition to show that $\frac{d}{dz}(z^2+2)=2z$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I need to show that $$\frac{d}{dz}(z^2+2)=2z$$
I am using the limit definition for complex variables which is $$f^1(z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}=\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}$$ to show this. I believe i have it solved but im not quite sure. This is what i have $$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}=\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z} \Rightarrow  \lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{[(z_0+\Delta z)^2+2]-(z^2+2)}{\Delta z}$$ $$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{z^2+2 \Delta z * z+\Delta z^2+2-z^2-2}{\Delta z}\Rightarrow\lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{2 \Delta z * z+\Delta z^2 }{\Delta z} $$ $$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}2z+\Delta z =2z+0=2z$$ So $2z$ is my final answer. Can anyone confirm, deny or point out mistakes with this? As i am new to Complex Analysis any info is welcome.

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: So its the same exact procedure as in calculus? Thanks.

Comment: @After_Sunset: Yes. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, but for a complex derivative you can approach from $\pm\epsilon$ or $\pm i \epsilon$ or from ${{7}\over\sqrt{58}}\epsilon-i{{3}\over \sqrt{58}}\epsilon$. You can make $\Delta z$ equal to any of those above mentioned variants however. Just realize you can approach 0 from more than just 2 directions, especially if your function isn't analytic, has a singularity. $ln{(z)}$ is a good example of when you need to be careful with the definition.

Comment: I don't understand what point you are getting at here?

Comment: These different paths of approaching the value only matter when you try to solve a limit by breaking it up into approaching from left and right, which isn't what op does here.

Comment: Your right, I was just trying to elaborate on what's going on inside the definition.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the extra info.